# After I upload my Wordpress website, if the used template gets automaticly updated, does it changes the on my website?

Tags: wordpress, templates

I'm starting to work on Wordpress and got to know that the templates used get update. I'm concerned that it might update when the website is online, and bring my template to it's original state. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a [Child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) and edit files in child theme.

Child theme will not be changed, if you have automatic updates enabled, and theme gets updated.

There are [many plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/child-theme/) available for this.

You can also create a child theme easily with [WP CLI](https://wp-cli.org/) on command line.

Example: `wp scaffold child-theme sample-theme --parent_theme=twentysixteen`

See [wp scaffold child-theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/scaffold/child-theme/) for more info.